# Python check if value in dictionary corresponds to value in another one

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key

I am looking for a solution that allows to check what recipes from a given list I can make from the ingredients I have in my fridge.
So both "recipes" and "fridge" are dictionaries.

The script I have does not take into account the values but only the keys.
I would like to find a solution that allows me to only find the result "salade" as this script would also take into account the values (values in recipes must be equal or under values in fridge).

```
    fridge = {
    "orange" : 5,
    "citron" : 3,
    "sel" : 100,
    "sucre" : 50,
    "farine" : 250,
    "lait" : 200,
    "oeufs" : 1,
    "tomates" : 6,
    "huile" : 100,
}
    
recipes = {
    "jus_de_fruit" : {
        "orange" : 3,
        "citron" : 1,
        "pomme" : 1
    },
    "salade" : {
        "tomates" : 4,
        "huile" : 10,
        "sel" : 3
    },
    "crepes" : {
        "lait" : 400,
        "farine" : 250,
        "oeufs" : 2
    }
}

def in_fridge(item):
    if item in dictionnaire_frigo:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def check_recipes(name):  
    for item in recipes[name]:
        item_in_fridge = in_fridge(item)
        if item_in_fridge == False:
            return False
    return True
for name in recipes:
    print(check_recipes(name))
```

outputs

false true true

```
if check_recipes(name) == True: print(name)
```

outputs

salade and crepe

but I want to find only salade as I don't have enough of the ingredient "lait" in my fridge and it should not output crepe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your input dictionaries `fridge` and `recipes` these two methods may solve your issue:

```
def in_fridge(ingredients: dict, fridge_food: dict) -> bool:
    
    for ingredient in ingredients:

        if ingredient not in fridge_food:
            return False

        if ingredients[ingredient] > fridge_food[ingredient]:
            return False

    return True

def check_recipes(recipes: dict, fridge_food: dict) -> None:

    for recipe in recipes:

        if in_fridge(recipes[recipe], fridge_food):

            print(f'There are enough ingredients to make {recipe}. ')
```

Using them with your dictionnaries

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    check_recipes(recipes, fridge)
```

outputs:

```
There are enough ingredients to make salade.
```

If you want, lets say a list of the recipes you can do, use instead:

```
def check_recipes(recipes: dict, fridge_food: dict) -> list:

    ans = []
    for recipe in recipes:

        if in_fridge(recipes[recipe], fridge_food):

            ans.append({recipe: recipes[recipe]})

    return ans
```

Then the output is

```
[{'salade': {'tomates': 4, 'huile': 10, 'sel': 3}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check how much oranges you have by using

```py
fridge["orange"]  # Awnser : 5
```

and how much you lait you need for doing crepes by using

```py
recipes["crepes"]["lait"]  # Awnser : 400
```

using these two commands, you should be able to do the comparisions you want.

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate and compare (keys first to find a match then values).
Just do:

```
for recipe, recipe_contents in recipes.items():
    if all(elem in list(fridge.keys()) for elem in list(recipes[recipe].keys())):
        if all(recipe_contents[elem] <= fridge[elem] for elem in recipe_contents):
            print(recipe)
```

The result is:

```
salade
```

Answer (score 0):

`collections.Counter` implements comparisons according to the exact logic you want, so you can make this very simple by making `Counter`s for the fridge contents and each recipe, and comparing them:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> for n, recipe in recipes.items():
...     if Counter(recipe) <= Counter(fridge):
...         print(n)
...
salade
```

If you needed to implement it without `Counter` for some reason, it's pretty simple to iterate over the items in `recipe` and compare each to the quantity in the fridge (this is the exact same thing that `Counter(recipe) <= Counter(fridge)` is doing behind the scenes:

```
>>> for n, recipe in recipes.items():
...     if all(c <= fridge.get(i, 0) for i, c in recipe.items()):
...         print(n)
...
salade
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def in_fridge(item):
    return item[0] in fridge.keys() and item[1] <= fridge[item[0]]
    
    
def check_recipes(name):  
    for item in recipes[name].items():
        if not in_fridge(item):
            return False
    return True
    
for name in recipes.keys():
    print(check_recipes(name))
    

False
True
False
```